# How do I block non-local domains from sending local mail through postfix?

Tags: email, postfix

I have postfix running under Alpine docker. If I start it up like so:

```
docker run --name local -it -p 2500:25 alpine sh
/ # apk update && apk add postfix
/ # newaliases
/ # mkdir /var/mail
/ # postfix start
```

Then from my host box I do:

```
$ telnet localhost 2500
EHLO whatever
MAIL FROM: whatever
RCPT TO: root
DATA
From: whatever
To: root
Subject: I'm not really on your server

And that's a problem!

.
```

It works and sends an email to root on the docker container. Boo. I don't want this at all. I would like for only localhost to be able to send messages sans domain (or on behalf of `$mydomain`).

Is it possible to do this with postfix, and if so, how?

Comment: by default postfix allows relay via `127.0.0.0/8`, do you want to disable that?

Comment: @hkdtam you mean localhost being able to relay email from wherever (presumably just localhost)? Nah, I'm not worried about that, I just don't want Random Joe on the internet to say that they're sending email *from inside my house*

Comment: as far as I can see your telnet test behaviour is normal (for a stock postfix on most distributions), if you want to apply more rigorous sender checks  (there are plethora), just migrate your question to ServerFault and you should get more valuable results